# Running Glassfish 4 on linux openshift cloud server with openjdk7

Tags: java-7, java, openshift, glassfish-4

Running glassfish 4 on linux openshift cloud server with openjdk7. I just can't start server giving me exceptions. I can run glassfish 3 with no problem. Any idea what causes this?

```
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@1651733 in service registry.
Completed shutdown of GlassFish runtime
We are in non-embedded mode, so org.glassfish.main.core.glassfish [107] has nothing to do.
Jun 26, 2013 8:08:18 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Jun 26, 2013 8:08:18 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Jun 26, 2013 8:08:18 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
Caused by: A MultiException has 8 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on org.glassfish.server.ServerEnvironmentImpl
3. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.enterprise.util.net.NetUtils
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on org.glassfish.server.ServerEnvironmentImpl
5. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.DomainXmlPersistence errors were found
6. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.DomainXmlPersistence
7. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml errors were found
8. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:84)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:229)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:311)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:448)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:118)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2204)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1149)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServices(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:651)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServices(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:639)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigurationPopulator.populateConfig(ConfigurationPopulator.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.bootstrap.HK2Populator.populateConfig(HK2Populator.java:158)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.populateConfig(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:211)
        at com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Main.createServiceLocator(Main.java:273)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.HK2Main.createServiceLocator(HK2Main.java:120)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime.newGlassFish(EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishRuntimeDecorator.newGlassFish(GlassFishRuntimeDecorator.java:68)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntime.newGlassFish(OSGiGlassFishRuntime.java:91)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:113)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.net.NetUtils.<clinit>(NetUtils.java:55)
        at com.sun.enterprise.universal.glassfish.ASenvPropertyReader$ASenvMap.getHostname(ASenvPropertyReader.java:310)
        at com.sun.enterprise.universal.glassfish.ASenvPropertyReader$ASenvMap.get(ASenvPropertyReader.java:153)
        at com.sun.enterprise.universal.glassfish.ASenvPropertyReader$ASenvMap.completeMap(ASenvPropertyReader.java:191)
        at com.sun.enterprise.universal.glassfish.ASenvPropertyReader$ASenvMap.entrySet(ASenvPropertyReader.java:171)
        at org.glassfish.server.ServerEnvironmentImpl.postConstruct(ServerEnvironmentImpl.java:165)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:281)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:328)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:448)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:118)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2204)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:549)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:191)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:214)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find com.sun.enterprise.util.LogMessages bundle
        at java.util.logging.Logger.setupResourceInfo(Logger.java:1400)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:256)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:399)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:315)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:408)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.CULoggerInfo.<clinit>(CULoggerInfo.java:61)
        ... 37 more
```

Comment: Pinchy, could you please put the link of that bug solution?. I'm still stuck on that one. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, there is no solution. I tried to run it on OpenShift With OpenJDK but it gave me this error. Now it's running, I guess OpenShift Admins did upgrade to a newer OpenJDK version. Try using newer version of OpenJDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can run GlassFish 4 on OpenShift. I have written quickstart which showcase that https://github.com/shekhargulati/glassfish4-openshift-quickstart

Comment: Thanks Shenkar, the problem was already resolved couple days ago, this issue happened because of a bug. But thanks for writing this tutorial I am sure it will be very useful for others.

Comment: @Pinchy What was the bug?

Comment: @Sti I don't know, OpenShift upgraded Java version and the problem disappeared. Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasted hours with OpenShift's Glassfish3 guide. I couldn't get it to start and your tutorial worked in five minutes!